# Run script only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the form like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="bubble2.php" id="bubbleName">
    <input id="myInput" name="namehere" type="text">
    <input name="submit" type="submit">  
</form>
```

And the script which prevents redirecting or reloading the page after submit:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'bubble.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                 $('#bubbleName')[0].reset();

            }
        });

   });
});
</script>
```

What I need is the script to run only once after submit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [one](https://api.jquery.com/one/) for that:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('form').one('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'bubble.php',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {

                 $('#bubbleName')[0].reset();

            }
        });

   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

first, add class name or id to the submit button and then add EventListener

```
 <form method="POST" action="bubble2.php" id="bubbleName">
   <input id="myInput" name="namehere" type="text">
   <input name="submit" type="submit" class="btn">  
 </form>

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener("click",function(){

  //enter your code here

};
```